# Unable to PHP echo in HTML CSS Div

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having trouble echoing with PHP in a `div`. It seems that, it only works when I remove the `div` tags from `<body>` and move them to the `<head>` without the `</div>`. But it is getting difficult when let's say I want to echo/print outputs in multiple `div` tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<!--<//?=isset($_POST['TextBox2'])?$_POST['TextBox2']:''?>-->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="" content="">

<link href="Untitled1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="index.php">
<a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:441px;top:967px;border-width:0;z-index:250"></a>
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:22px;width:159px;height:46px;line-height:46px;z-index:1;"
 name="TextBox1" value="" placeholder="TextBox1">

<input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:312px;top:22px;width:156px;height:46px;line-height:46px;z-index:2;"
 name="TextBox2" value="" placeholder="TextBox2">

<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="ADD" value="ADD" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:228px;width:72px;height:25px;z-index:3;">
<input type="submit" id="Button2" name="SUBSTRACT" value="SUBSTRACT" style="position:absolute;left:196px;top:228px;width:106px;height:25px;z-index:4;">
<input type="submit" id="Button3" name="MULTIPLY" value="MULTIPLY" style="position:absolute;left:312px;top:228px;width:84px;height:25px;z-index:5;">
<input type="submit" id="Button4" name="CLEAR" value="CLEAR" style="position:absolute;left:406px;top:228px;width:76px;height:25px;z-index:6;">

<div id="contents" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:92px;width:369px;height:130px;z-index:7;  overflow-y: scroll;background-color:yellow">

<p></p><!--</div>-->
<!--<button name='submit' value='1'>ADD_PHP</button>-->
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function load() {
        var     storedValue1 = localStorage.getItem('val1');
        var     storedValue2 = localStorage.getItem('val2');

        if (storedValue1)   {
        document.getElementById('Editbox1').value = storedValue1;
        }   
        if (storedValue2)   {
        document.getElementById('Editbox2').value = storedValue2;
        }       
                 }



$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Editbox1').focus();


 $("#Button1").click(function(){ 

var fieldValue1 = document.getElementById('Editbox1').value;
var fieldValue2 = document.getElementById('Editbox2').value;

    localStorage.setItem('val1', fieldValue1);
    localStorage.setItem('val2', fieldValue2);
                        }); // button 1 click

  $("#Button4").click(function(){

    document.getElementById('Editbox1').value = '';
    document.getElementById('Editbox2').value = '';
    localStorage.removeItem('val1');    
    localStorage.removeItem('val2');    
        $("div").empty();

                        }); //button 4 click                        
});//document.ready


</script>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if (isset($_POST['TextBox1'])){
echo $_POST['Textbox1'];}

function input(){

global $input_string1;
global $input_string2;

$input_string1 = $_POST["TextBox1"];
$input_string2 = $_POST["TextBox2"];

return ($input_string1);
return ($input_string2);
                }

function add(){
input();
global $input_string1;
global $input_string2;



echo "<div id='contents'>"."input string 1: ".$input_string1. "</br> "."</div>"; 
echo "<div id='contents'>"."input string 2: ".$input_string2. "</br> "."</div>";  ;

$result = ($input_string1 + $input_string2);
echo "<div id='contents'>". "addition is :  ".$result . "</br> "."</div>"; ;

}




if($_POST['ADD']=='ADD'){
input();
global $input_string1;
global $input_string2;
if ($input_string1 <> NULL and $input_string2 <> NULL  ){
    add();
    }

else {echo "<div id='contents'>"."<br>"."Please type valid numbers !! "."</br>"."</div>";;}
                       }

if($_POST['SUBSTRACT']=='SUBSTRACT'){

}

?>
</head>
<body onload ="load()">


<!--<div id="contents" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:92px;width:369px;height:130px;z-index:7;background-color:yellow"></div>-->


<!--<img src="images/img0001.png" id="Shape1" alt="" style="width:369px;height:130px;"></div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your div to the <body> tag - you're trying to print in the <head>!

Comment: and this isn't proper tag `</br>`, it's `<br/>`. Your HTML's messed up. Your HTML markup's wrong. You have way too many errors in your code. Time to learn what HTML 101 is.

Answer (score 0):

You need two files (1) HTML page and (2) `index.php` file for results, as in the form you have `action = "index.php". I also suggest that use external-style instead of inline-style as it is difficult to debug your code. I tested the following codes and works on my machine.

Your code for HTML page would be as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <!--<//?=isset($_POST['TextBox2'])?$_POST['TextBox2']:''?>-->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <meta name="" content="">

    <link href="Untitled1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var storedValue1 = localStorage.getItem('val1');
            var storedValue2 = localStorage.getItem('val2');

            if (storedValue1) {
                document.getElementById('Editbox1').value = storedValue1;
            }
            if (storedValue2) {
                document.getElementById('Editbox2').value = storedValue2;
            }
        }



        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#Editbox1').focus();


            $("#Button1").click(function() {

                var fieldValue1 = document.getElementById('Editbox1').value;
                var fieldValue2 = document.getElementById('Editbox2').value;

                localStorage.setItem('val1', fieldValue1);
                localStorage.setItem('val2', fieldValue2);
            }); // button 1 click

            $("#Button4").click(function() {

                document.getElementById('Editbox1').value = '';
                document.getElementById('Editbox2').value = '';
                localStorage.removeItem('val1');
                localStorage.removeItem('val2');
                $("div").empty();

            }); //button 4 click                        
        }); //document.ready

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">

    <form name="form1" Method="POST" Action="index.php">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:441px;top:967px;border-width:0;z-index:250"></a>
        <input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:22px;width:159px;height:46px;line-height:46px;z-index:1;" name="TextBox1" value="" placeholder="TextBox1">

        <input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:312px;top:22px;width:156px;height:46px;line-height:46px;z-index:2;" name="TextBox2" value="" placeholder="TextBox2">

        <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="ADD" value="ADD" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:228px;width:72px;height:25px;z-index:3;">
        <input type="submit" id="Button2" name="SUBSTRACT" value="SUBSTRACT" style="position:absolute;left:196px;top:228px;width:106px;height:25px;z-index:4;">
        <input type="submit" id="Button3" name="MULTIPLY" value="MULTIPLY" style="position:absolute;left:312px;top:228px;width:84px;height:25px;z-index:5;">
        <input type="submit" id="Button4" name="CLEAR" value="CLEAR" style="position:absolute;left:406px;top:228px;width:76px;height:25px;z-index:6;">
    </form>

    <div id="contents" style="position:absolute;left:113px;top:92px;width:369px;height:130px;z-index:7;  overflow-y: scroll;background-color:yellow">
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

And your PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        if (isset($_POST['TextBox1'])){
        echo $_POST['Textbox1'];}

        function input(){
            global $input_string1;
            global $input_string2;

            $input_string1 = $_POST["TextBox1"];
            $input_string2 = $_POST["TextBox2"];

            return ($input_string1);
            return ($input_string2);
        }

        function add(){
            input();
            global $input_string1;
            global $input_string2;

            echo "<div id='contents'>"."input string 1: ".$input_string1. "</br> "."</div>"; 
            echo "<div id='contents'>"."input string 2: ".$input_string2. "</br> "."</div>";

            $result = ($input_string1 + $input_string2);
            echo "<div id='contents'>". "addition is :  ".$result . "</br> "."</div>";
        }


        if($_POST['ADD']=='ADD'){
            input();
            global $input_string1;
            global $input_string2;
                if ($input_string1 <> NULL and $input_string2 <> NULL  ){
                    add();
                    }

                else {
                    echo "<div id='contents'>"."<br>"."Please type valid numbers !! "."</br>"."</div>";
                }
            }

        if($_POST['SUBSTRACT']=='SUBSTRACT'){
        }

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you 100% sure about this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Echo div or any other element in `<head>` tag will not work for him. If it is moved to body, so for sure, it should work. There is no other error in his document that prevents echoing the content.

Comment: Putting PHP directives inside `<body></body>`. I wouldn't do that. and error reporting should be their first lines. Proper seperation of PHP directives and what's being echo'd as rendered HTML is best.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. I noticed that later. I revised my answer.

Comment: @Minhan Nijat....thanks for help...but...I'm trying to display the results in the div tag <div id='contents'>....with ur help the results are redirected index.php page...I want the results displayed on the same page without being the redirection!!!